# Training gradually gets slower

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When calling `Model.fit()` many times (thousands), each call takes longer and longer. It might start at 150 us/sample and after 30 minutes or so, it's 300 us/sample and keeps getting slower. If I leave it running overnight, it's maybe about 10 times slower the next day.

You can see the increasing space between points in this graph of 10 hours of training.
[image: training graph from Tensorboard]

The slowness persists between models that start fresh without a checkpoint, so it's not that it has to do more work later in the training. It resets to fast if I restart the application so it's not my computer slowing down.

I call `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` between every 20 calls to Model.fit() and that prevents a memory leak, but doesn't help this "speed leak".

Comment: TensorFlow issue tracker might be a more appropriate place to post this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues. I'd recommend to also include a reproducer, because if this is reproducible, it's clearly a bug.

Comment: Already put there https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33315